# Download csv file via submit button in R

Tags: r, csv, automation, web-scraping

I want to automate the following task in R:

Go to the following page with historical data:
http://www.ariva.de/XXX/historische_kurse,
where the XXX stands for some ticker, like e.g. DBX0BT

So the URL in this case would be: 
http://www.ariva.de/DBX0BT/historische_kurse

At the right hand bottom there is a button `Download`.

I want to create a function which takes as input:

- ticker
- from date (von)
- to date (bis)
- path

and then downloads the resulting csv file by "pressing the `Download` button" to the location path given by path.

**My question**
How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you have a list of [WKN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wertpapierkennnummer) or [ISIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Securities_Identification_Number) you can just run this and read/download the files. You can also scrape the WKN/ISINs but that will be much more complicated from this webpage and I assume you have access to such information.

```
library(XML)

wkn<-c("DBX0BT","865985") #some stock IDs (WKN) for your targets 
date.F<-"12.5.2014" #from when for historical data
date.T<-"12.5.2015" #to when

for(j in 1:length(wkn)){
tg<-htmlParse(paste0("http://www.ariva.de/",wkn[j],"/historische_kurse")) #parse the historical webpage
atbts<-xpathSApply(tg,'//div[@class="content left abstand"]/input') #extract attributes for that stock so we can download it

secu<-sapply(atbts, function(x) xmlAttrs(x)['value'])[1] #security id (only relevant for downloading)
boerseid<-sapply(atbts, function(x) xmlAttrs(x)['value'])[2] #boerse id (only relevant for downloading)

#download, read and assign the values
assign(wkn[j],read.csv(paste0("http://www.ariva.de/quote/historic/historic.csv?secu=",secu,"&boerse_id=",boerseid,
               "&clean_split=1&clean_payout=0&clean_bezug=1&min_time=",date.F,"&max_time=",date.T,"&trenner=%3B&go=Download"),
               sep=";"))
write.csv(get(wkn[j]),paste0(wkn[j],".csv"))
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain (or point into the right direction) how you figured this URL out? I'm looking at the ariva page with the Firefox Inspector, but there's no hints for these parameters, is there?

Comment: I used Chrome browser and used "inspect element" by right-clicking. By going to the tab called "Network" inside "inspect element" I can see the "Request URL" and the query parameters.